# Why it did not parse correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I am currently using NSXML parser to parse my data. I can pass all data successfully accept an element who's values are "A, B, C depressor stick & D $10+".

I can only grab "D $10+".

I suspect it is because of this that is located under parser foundCharacters:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
//NSLog(@"foundCharacters: %@", string);    
currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *)[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

}
```

However, I have no idea on what to replace it that method with as I afraid that it might affect all the other elements that I could parse properly previously.

This is part of the output of the parsed document:

```
<title>Cleansing, gel, Tongue depressor stick &amp; gloves $10+</title>
```

The output of foundCharacters are as shown below

```
foundCharacters: Cleansing, gel,  Tongue depressor stick 
foundCharacters: &
foundCharacters:  gloves $10+
```

And I have appended the string under didEndElement:

```
[currentIssue.title appendString:currentNodeContent];
```

Comment: Can't understand! What is the value of "string" in the delegate function? Did you get the correct values?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, the value is "A, B, C depressor stick & D $10+". But I only managed to grab "D $10+".

Comment: @Confused_person: Note that `foundCharacters` can be called more than once for one XML element, you have to *append* the strings. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986699/nsxmlparser-dont-get-all-the-tag-if-the-tag-have-accent/14987201#14987201.

Comment: Yes. I have also tried appending it under foundCharacters. I also tried appending it under didEndElement with no success. The problem is, it only grab the contents after "&" currently for this element.

Comment: @Confused_person: What does the original XML look like? Is the "&" properly escaped as `&amp;`?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. But the original parsed xml data contains "&amp".

Comment: Uncomment your NSLog statement and show the output.

Comment: Here is part of the output of the parsed document, "<title>Cleansing, gel,  Tongue depressor stick &amp; gloves $10+</title>"

Comment: What I meant is: Add the the output of the `NSLog(@"foundCharacters: %@", string);` statement to your question. - You probably have to show a complete XML input and all your code in order to get help, because the "&" character (escaped as `&amp;`) normally does not make any problems with NSXMLParser.

Comment: Btw: How is this different from your (similar looking) previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179258/why-does-this-not-parse-correctly, which you solved yourself?

Comment: Previous question was more about initializing issues to get the correct count of objects.

Comment: @Confused_person: You make it difficult to help! You said that you tried appending the strings in foundCharacters, but you don't show the code. I asked for the output of `NSLog(@"foundCharacters: %@", string);`, but you don't show it. - Without providing more concrete information, this will probably be closed as "duplicate" (which it might or might not be) or as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Sorry. I was unsure of your request previously. Updated.

Comment: @Confused_person: Your NSLog output shows that it is exactly as I said: foundCharacters is called multiple times for the XML element, and you have to collect and append the strings. - (Now voting as "duplicate".)

Comment: I have already appended it as I mentioned before under didEndElement. "[something.title appendString:currentNodeContent];"

Comment: @Confused_person: Your NSLog output shows clearly that `foundCharacters` is called tree times: First time with " Cleansing, gel,  Tongue depressor stick", second time with "&", and finally with " gloves $10+". You have to append in `foundCharacters`, not in `didEndElement`!

Comment: Yes I have tried that with no success. However, when I changed the initialization to "initWithString:string", I can see all the data but everything goes haywire after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the node name and in didfound characters,for that particular node do not trim the node value.

Comment: Yes I have did that. It still does not store whatever contents parsed before &.

Comment: the ivar currentNodeContent is having some problem.. Dont use mutablestring make it a string and don't set it to nil anywhere.

Comment: 1. I changed it to "initWithString:string. 2. I appended it under foundCharacters. 3. I assigned the currentNodeContent to an element under didEndElement, then set it to nil. It works after that.